# How to check if opcode cache is running on a server?

Tags: php, linux, opcode

Is it possible to check if a PHP opcode cache is installed and running on a server without having SSH access to the server? I've checked phpinfo() and can see no reference to APC or eAccelerator, but I'm aware there are other opcode cache systems and am not totally sure that checking phpinfo() is enough to let me know one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

`var_dump(function_exists('apc_store'));` or equivalent for the library of your choice.

If using a web server SAPI, as per usual, make sure you restart the server process after editing your php.ini to see the new additions reflected.

Comment: Thanks. So without knowing which library it is, I'd run through this check for all of the known opcode libraries?

Comment: Well, yeah. There's not one big "opcode cache" install bundle. In fact, unless you manually compiled your php version including the extensions in question, they won't be available by default. It's something you'll need to add yourself with a dynamic extension. PECL/PEAR is the simplest way to do this. There was some debate about adding APC to the default PHP5.4 distribution but that ended up not happening. Further, the only two libraries that many people use (in my experience) are **apc** and **Xcache**, so it's not like there's some long list of libraries to check for.